# Updating a table from another table with multiple columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to update multiple columns of one table according to other multiple columns of another table in SQLAlchemy. I'm using SQLite when testing it, so I can't use the `UPDATE table1 SET col=val WHERE table1.key == table2.key" syntax.

In other words, I'm trying to create this sort of update query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET 
   col1 = (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.key == table1.key), 
   col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.key == table1.key)
```

In SQLAlchemy:

```
select_query1 = select([table2.c.col1]).where(table1.c.key == table2.c.key)
select_query2 = select([table2.c.col2]).where(table1.c.key == table2.c.key)
session.execute(table.update().values(col1=select_query1, col2=select_query2))
```

Only I'd like to do the query only once instead of twice, unless SQLite and MySQL are smart enough not to make that query twice themselves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613777/sqlalchemy-correlated-update-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Thus, this is not really an answer, but it is far too long for a comment.

You can easily compose your query with 2 columns (I guess you already knew that):

```
select_query = select([table2.c.col1, table2.c.col2]).where(table1.c.key == table2.c.key)
```

and afterwards you can use the method `with_only_columns()`, see [api](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns):

```
In[52]: print(table.update().values(col1 = select_query.with_only_columns([table2.c.col1]), col2 = select_query.with_only_columns([table2.c.col2])))
UPDATE table SET a=(SELECT tweet.id 
FROM tweet 
WHERE tweet.id IS NOT NULL), b=(SELECT tweet.user_id 
FROM tweet 
WHERE tweet.id IS NOT NULL)
```

But as you see from the update statement, you will be effectivelly doing two selects. (Sorry I did not adapt the output completely to your example, but I'm sure you get the idea).

I'm not sure whether, as you say, `MySQL` will be smart enough to make it one query only. I guess so. Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: It's helpful in ensuring I have no better alternative :) I ended up doing that when using SQLite and the UPDATE FROM query with MySQL (the query using select doesn't work in MySQL since it's from a temporary table and you can't use a temp table twice in one query).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613777/sqlalchemy-correlated-update-with-multiple-columns