# SQLAlchemy correlated update for multiple columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have been able to used the correlated update construct shown in the docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html#correlated-updates) to update one column in a table.

For example:

```
sel = select([UpdateTable.column]).\
      where(UpdateTable.id == OrigTable.id)

up = update(OrigTable).values(column=sel)
```

Which produces SQL like:

```
UPDATE origtable SET column=(SELECT updatetable.column
FROM updatetable
WHERE updatetable.id = origtable.id)
```

Is it possible to use the Declaritive or Query Api to update multiple columns for a selection?

I am trying to emulate something like the following in PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE origtable
   SET
     column1 = updatetable.column1,
     column2 = updatetable.column2
   FROM updatetable 
   WHERE origtable.id == updatetable.id
```

EDIT:

It seems that formatting this a single statement may not be possible with the current SQLAlchemy api.

However, a workaround using two selects seems possible using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185056/updating-a-table-from-another-table-with-multiple-columns-in-sqlalchemy/30211905#30211905).

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185056/updating-a-table-from-another-table-with-multiple-columns-in-sqlalchemy/30211905#30211905) is not optimal but might be closed enough for what you need.

Comment: Thanks @lrnzcig, I thought something like that might be possible.
I guess the current api doesn't support this directly.

Comment: You're welcome. (If it helped, may I suggest a +1 for the solution linked. Thanks.)

Comment: @lrnzcig. Done, thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613777/sqlalchemy-correlated-update-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is for Postgresql, we can use SQLAlchemy's [multiple table update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#multiple-table-updates) support. The documentation is for Core only, but the [Query API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) is built atop Core, and we can [apply that knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543223/how-do-you-express-a-multi-table-update-update-from-in-sqlalchemy-orm/42552298#42552298):

```
session.query(OrigTable).\
    filter(OrigTable.id == UpdateTable.id).\
    update({OrigTable.column1: UpdateTable.column1,
            OrigTable.column2: UpdateTable.column2},
           synchronize_session=False)
```

which results in

```
UPDATE origtable
SET column1=updatetable.column1,
    column2=updatetable.column2
FROM updatetable
WHERE origtable.id = updatetable.id
```