# SQLAlchemy Correlated Update with Multiple Columns?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, correlated-subquery

This question has been asked multiple times on stackoverflow, but they all appeared to be over a year old so I figured I would ask again in case there has been an update.

A `correlated update` is an update statement that updates all rows in one table based on values from another table, while linking the two tables together.

From the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-updates), we can do a correlated update easily but only on a single column:

```
update(foo).values(bar=select([foobar.c.bar]).where(foobar.c.id == foo.c.id))
```

This translates into:

```
UPDATE foo
SET bar = (
    SELECT bar
    FROM foobar
    WHERE foobar.id = foo.id
)
```

How can we write a correlated update using more than one column in sqlalchemy? For example:

```
UPDATE foo
SET (bar, baz) = (
    SELECT bar, baz
    FROM foobar
    WHERE foobar.id = foo.id
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your avatar and description I'm guessing you're using Oracle. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031405/2681632) one can device the following SQLAlchemy concotion, if your join results in a [key preserved view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11783):

```
stmt = select([foo.c.bar.label('foo_bar'),
               foo.c.baz.label('foo_baz'),
               foobar.c.bar.label('foobar_bar'),
               foobar.c.baz.label('foobar_baz')]).\
    where(foo.c.id == foobar.c.id)

update(stmt).values({stmt.c.foo_bar: stmt.c.foobar_bar,
                     stmt.c.foo_baz: stmt.c.foobar_baz})
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
UPDATE (SELECT foo.bar AS foo_bar,
               foo.baz AS foo_baz,
               foobar.bar AS foobar_bar,
               foobar.baz AS foobar_baz
        FROM foo, foobar
        WHERE foo.id = foobar.id)
SET foo_bar=foobar_bar, foo_baz=foobar_baz
```

The labels are important since your tables share column names.

You can also produce your original target SQL:

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_, select, exists

stmt = select([foobar.c.bar, foobar.c.baz]).where(foo.c.id == foobar.c.id)
foo.update().\
    values({tuple_(foo.c.bar, foo.c.baz).self_group(): stmt}).\
    where(exists(stmt))
```

The [`self_group()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement.self_group) call is important, as the compiler seems to omit the parentheses around the tuple, producing incorrect syntax, in this case. I added the WHERE clause in order to avoid updating *foo* rows with no matching *foobar*:

```
UPDATE foo SET (bar, baz)=(SELECT foobar.bar, foobar.baz 
FROM foobar 
WHERE foo.id = foobar.id) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT foobar.bar, foobar.baz 
FROM foobar 
WHERE foo.id = foobar.id)
```

Comment: You are a hero; thank you! I would ask that you spam this answer on every `correlated update with multiple columns` question that you can find!

Comment: Is there any benefit to using your first approach over the second approach?

Comment: I guess not having to do the separate EXISTS test in order to not update unmatching rows in the 1st approach is a benefit compared to 2nd. Though the 1st approach might better support complex joined views, it is limited by [key preservation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11783). That might or might not force you to go for the 2nd approach in some cases. I have very little to no experience with Oracle, so I'll have to leave finding out the details to the reader.